# Shorten empty lines to one line c# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text like

```
This is a line




This is other line







This is another line
```

**How to get rid of those multi empty lines ?**

What I want is

```
This is a line

This is other line

This is another line
```

**\s** says that matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks) but I cannot figure out how to make multi empty line to just one empty line ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing multiple blank lines with one blank line using RegEx search and replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475042/replacing-multiple-blank-lines-with-one-blank-line-using-regex-search-and-replac)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\r?\n\s*){2,}", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

`\r` being optional lets it work with Unix-style line terminators.  The output will have Windows-style terminators, though.

`\s*` allows it to match on lines that contain whitespace.  (I had originally put in a `?` here to make the match non-greedy, but that's not actually necessary and possibly detrimental in this case. In .NET regular expressions, `\s` and `.` don't match newlines with the default `RegexOptions`.)

`{2,}` makes sure it will only match with two successive newlines separated only by whitespace.