# Replace multiple blank lines in text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hopefully a simple question.

If I have text like this:

```
Orange
Apples


Melons

Bananas
```

...how can I replace all occurrences of *multiple* blank lines with single blank lines, ending up with this:

```
Orange
Apples

Melons

Bananas
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4pT/
Need to remove multiple blank lines from the first box's input before inserting into the second.

I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475642), but am not sure how to use that regular expression in Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you have 3 blank lines, that upon replacing the double blank, becomes another double blank, and your regex has moved on and is satisfied?

Comment: Have you considered that one/some blank lines could be full of non-newline whitespace, and what should happen to those lines?

Comment: Edited to make it clear that the aim is to remove multiple blank lines, not necessarily just two.  Basically, if there's more than one blank line in a row, reduce down to just one.

Comment: Try this regex: /^\s*[\r\n]/gm

Answer (score 6):

*This is an old question, but I don't care, it comes up first in Google search.*

You can do this with the following code:

```
var EOL = string.match(/\r\n/gm)?"\r\n":"\n";
var regExp = new RegExp("("+EOL+"){3,}", "gm");
string = string.replace(regExp, EOL+EOL);
```

- First it determines the endline char to use in Regex
- Regex looks for EOL chars being repeated 3 or more times, and replaces them with 2 EOL chars.
- Using `g` modifier to replace all occurrences
- Using `m` modifier to apply regex to the whole multi-line string, instead of per line.

Answer (score 2):

Just use it like this:

```
var inputString = '...';
var outputString = inputString.replace(/^(\s*\r\n){2,}/, "\r\n")
```

Comment: Wont this replace 2 or more (alot more) with a single line-break?

Comment: Hi - couldn't get this to work in my case.  I've added a fiddle to illustrate the problem better: http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4pT/  Need to get input from first textarea and remove multiple blank lines before adding to the second.  Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1):

> Other one-liner answers in this thread are wrong while those won't replace all new lines sequences with 2 new lines but will do that only once. Those will run once over the string. Which means if there will be 6 new lines, i twill replace 3 to 2 and next 3 to 2 again. So result would be 4 new lines. Then you would need to run this code again, which would replace 3 new lines with 2 and leftover of 1 new line would be untouched, so after 2nd run you would have 3 new lines. If you would run for the 3rd time only then you would reduce from 6 new lines to just 2.

So the correct one-liner answer is this:

`yourString.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]|^\s+| +(?= )| +$|\s+$(?![^])/gm, '\n\n');`

Full sample:

```js
const a = `





a




b





`;

const result = a.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]|^\s+| +(?= )| +$|\s+$(?![^])/gm, '\n\n');

console.log(result);
```

Result will be as you would expect:

[image]

---

**Why other answers are wrong? Check this out:**

[image]

See \n for all "new line"

[image]

Replaced some, but not all

[image]

Replaced some, but not all again

Answer (score 0):

Using simple regular expressions:

```
str = "whatever your string is";
reg = /\n\n\n/;
str.replace(reg, "\n\n");
```